# malloc() function in C

Tags: c, malloc

Can anyone please explain this?

```
struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node * link; 
} 
main() 
{
    struct node *p, *list, *temp; 
    list = p = temp = NULL; 
    ......................... 
    ......................... 
} 

addbeg() 
{ 
    int x;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    scanf("%d", &x); 
    temp->data=x;
    temp->link = list;
    list=temp;
}
```

This is a code for entering data in linked list through C language. The code is not complete, but I think its enough for the purpose. Please explain the coding basically these lines:

```
 temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

and

```
 temp->link = list;
 list=temp;.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`malloc()` is used to allocate memory - in this case for a new node.

The `addbeg()` function defined in your code does the following:

1. Defines a temporary variable `x`.
2. Allocates space for a new node.
3. Inputs an integer (`%d` code to `scanf`) and stores it in `x`.
4. Stores the value that was saved to `x` in the data field of the newly allocated node.
5. Stores the old "head" of the list pointed to by the variable '`list`' as a link in the newly allocated node.
6. Sets the new node to be the new head of the list stored in the variable '`list`'.

It's a very basic implementation of a linked list (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) of integers.

Comment: You could usefully add a note that the code should eventually ensure that the memory for each allocation is released with `free()`, muttering about 'memory leaks' and 'does not matter so much for small learning programs but does in big long-running ones', so you may as well learn how to do it right on small learning programs too.

Comment: his program won't work anyway though, unless `list` and `temp` are either passed to addbeg(), or addbeg() is defined within main.

Comment: addbeg cannot be defined within main in standard C.  Some compilers allow it as an extension, but it is not valid C.

Comment: Firstly the code is not completed, may be we could pass temp and 
list to addbeg() or may be I should declare temp and list outside 
main as global variable,but I pick this code from a book, cause I 
didn't understand it. Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

malloc allocates space for a new node.

```
temp->link = list
```

and

```
list = temp
```

makes that new node the head of your list.

Answer (score 0):

first line: Allocate memory for a single additional node of the list.

second line: Attach the current list as the continuation after this element.

third line: Make the current element the beginning of a list.

Answer (score 0):

temp and list aren't visible in addbeg, since they're declared in main. They either need to be passed in to addbeg or declared outside of main (global, yuck).